# Push notifications forcing web app into landscape

Tags: javascript, android, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm sending notifications from a web app. On a desktop this works fine, but when I send the notifications to a phone, tapping on the notification opens the web app... but only in landscape. Not only that, but it refuses to let me change to portrait, even when I change the orientation to portrait in settings?

I'm not sure what code I'd need to include, so here is the `manifest.json` of the web app and the `serviceWorker.js` for the notifications.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My Web App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/android-icon-36x36.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 0.75
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/android-icon-48x48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 1.0
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/android-icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 1.5
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/android-icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 2.0
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/android-icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 3.0
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/android-icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 4.0
    }
  ],
  "short_name": "App",
  "description": "It should work",
  "start_url": "index.php",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait" // Why is this not doing anything!
}
```

**serviceWorker.js**

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    if (!(self.Notification && self.Notification.permission === 'granted')) {
        return;
    }

    const sendNotification = content => {
        const title = content.title;
        const options = {
          body: content.body,
          icon: "/images/notify/logox.png",
          badge: "/images/notify/badge.png",
          vibrate: [100,600,100,100,600],
          actions: [
            {
              title: "Action",
              icon: "/images/action.png",
              action: "default-action"
            }
          ]
        };

        return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
    };

    if (event.data) {
        const message = event.data.json();
        event.waitUntil(sendNotification(message));
    }
});
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    let url = 'http://example.com/';
    event.notification.close(); // Android needs explicit close.
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then( windowClients => {
            // Check if there is already a window/tab open with the target URL
            for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                var client = windowClients[i];
                // If so, just focus it.
                if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                    return client.focus();
                }
            }
            // If not, then open the target URL in a new window/tab.
            if (clients.openWindow) {
                return clients.openWindow(url);
            }
        })
    );
});
```

When I open the web app from the start screen (on Android) it opens in portrait, as it should. Why is this happening when I open it from the notification?
What is going on here?

Comment: Try opening an [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) if you think this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the user device orientation to portrait using

```
screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
```

Examples found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/#examples)